# How to save my own object with NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, save, nskeyedarchiver

i've got problems using the NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver for saving my object.
I added the methods `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder` and `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder`. The problem is when i try to save the object it doesn't work correctly.
I could imagine a problem (but I'm not sure if it is the problem ;) ). I have some arrays within my object. They contain more objects (I implemented both of the "Coder"-Methods as well). So does the array call the methods in it's objects?

Any possible solution??

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure all the objects you are trying to archive are archivable? I don't have the list to hand but it's mostly the primitives. NSString, NSNumber, NSValue and a few more.

Comment: Did you use `encodeObject:forKey:` to encode in a keyed archive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the header file indicate that your class will implement the `NSCoding` protocol, like `<NSCoding>`

In the `encodeWithCoder` method you need to encode all the fields you want to save like so:

```
[encoder encodeObject:array1 forKey:@"array1"];
```

Then in the `initWithCoder` method, decode the fields that were encoded:

```
array1 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"array1"];
```

Be sure that any encoded containers only contain objects that also implement the `NSCoding` protocol. This could be core classes such as `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, as well as your own custom object.

If your project is not using garbage collection you need to retain or copy the data retrieved from the archive like so:

```
array1 = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"array1"] retain];
```

Comment: Well... now I have the next problem: How do I act when I have a object inherited by my other own object. One worked well, but as soon as I inherit it it does not work

Comment: - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder{if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]){